# How to make combination of a string using list of words for each position

Tags: python, list, format, combinations, cartesian-product

I have a list of strings like this:

```
original_text = "womens wear apparel bike"
```

Now, each word of `original_text` will have alternative words, like this list:

```
text_to_generate = [['females', 'ladies'], 'wear', ['clothing', 'clothes'], ['biking', 'cycling', 'running']]
```

I want to generate all possible phrases using the combination of the words in that list. I want something like this:

```
text1 = 'females wear clothing biking'
text2 = 'females wear clothes cycling'
text3 = 'ladies wear clothing biking'
text4 = 'ladies wear clothes cycling'
text5 = 'ladies wear clothes running'
```

The length of the word lists might not be all same.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
original_text = "womens wear apparel bike"
alternates_dict = {
    "mens": ["males"],
    "vitamins": ["supplements"],
    "womens": ["females", "ladies"],
    "shoes": ["footwear"],
    "apparel": ["clothing", "clothes"],
    "kids": ["childrens", "childs"],
    "motorcycle": ["motorbike"],
    "watercraft": ["boat"],
    "medicine": ["medication"],
    "supplements": ["vitamins"],
    "t-shirt": ["shirt"],
    "pram": ["stroller"],
    "bike": ["biking", "cycling"],
}

splitted = original_text.split()
for i in range(0,len(splitted)):
    if splitted[i] in alternates_dict.keys():
        splitted[i] = alternates_dict[splitted[i]]
        for word in splitted[i]:
            update  = original_text.replace(original_text.split()[i], word)
            print(update)
print(splitted)
```

Comment: "itertools.product" may help. If you have a specific issue while solving this yourself you can ask here with your code.

Comment: Have a look at [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/ask). "How to solve this problem with code" is not [on topic for StackOverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). Try to [make an honest attempt](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) at solving the problem yourself, and then feel free to ask specific questions about your solution, or problems with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a look into the [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) module. You will find many useful combinatorics related built-ins, including [`product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product), which give the [cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of all the elements of the passed lists.

In you case, you could do something like this:

```
from itertools import product

template = "{} wear {} {}"
options = [
  ['women', 'females', 'ladies'],
  ['apparel', 'clothing', 'clothes'],
  ['biking', 'cycling', 'running']
]

print(*(template.format(*ops) for ops in product(*options)), sep='\n')
```

> women wear apparel biking
> women wear apparel cycling
> women wear apparel running
> women wear clothing biking
> ...
> females wear clothing running
> females wear clothes biking
> ...
> ladies wear clothes running

---

I see in your edit that you are using a dictionary as source of options. The solution in this case would be almost the same, but combining the dictionary values instead and joining them back with the keys with [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip).

from itertools import product

```
template = "{women} wear {apparel} {bike}"
options = {
  'women': ['females', 'ladies'],
  'apparel': ['clothing', 'clothes'],
  'bike': ['biking', 'cycling', 'running']
}

combos = (zip(options.keys(), vals) for vals in product(*options.values()))
print(*(template.format(**dict(ops)) for ops in combos), sep='\n')
```

Comment: Oh, I see in your edit that you are using some sort of a `dict` and keys. The solution would not be so much different that this one, please let me know if you need help with adapting it.

Comment: Hey, your solution is working. I just tested with a few texts. I will test with my whole list and see if it works. I will comment here if it works fine with my whole list of string.

Comment: Check my Edit, It accounts for using a dict instead of a list